# Creating GoogleSignInOptions...?

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase, token

whille creating GoogleSignInoptions I fallow the steps presented on 'firebase' site 
that are as fallow:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

and just wondering what is that String that I'm passing there -R.string.default_web_client_id - and can it vary or is it always "R.string.default_web_client_id" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is that String

[It's automatically generated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/) and you can see it at

**`app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_flavor}/values/values.xml`**

> can it vary or is it always "R.string.default_web_client_id"?

Since it is generated by compiling Google Services, it is always the same (at least until Google decides to rename it with an API update).

Comment: this is not a string created by me - it's in 'R.java' and is declered as ' public static final int '  so to look there doesn't help me...

Comment: `R.string` is generated from `strings.xml`, if you do not have a `default_web_client_id`, you might need to add it

Comment: ok -but so it can be random String and it will not mather..?:S (have no knowladge of servers so have hard time to wrap my head around that :/ )

Comment: You don't need knowledge of a server here. What you have is an API key. By compiling the Google Services with Firebase, a key is generated for you. According to that last link, it is in the mentioned file.

Comment: yeap-got confused after readingin first link: "...equires that the server client ID be specified" but the second link explained alot - thank U @cricket_007 (y):)

Comment: @cricket_007 `R.string.default_web_client_id` is in a `values.xml` that is auto-generated by the Google Service plugin. It won't be in the OPs own `values.xml`. See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Right, that is similar documentation to the Firebase page.